# Cant find LongListSelectorItem in Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, longlistselector

I'm trying to use `LongListSelectorItem` in my wp7 app. But I cant find it in my assembly. So, i downloaded example from [here](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Improvements-in-the-LongListSelector-Selection-with-Nov-11-release-of-WP-Toolkit). In example all works fine, and I can use `LongListSelectorItem` in that project. But in my project, in `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit` there is no `LongListSelectorItem`, only `LongListSelector`. So, I removed my assemply `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit`, and added `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit` exactly from that example. But even after this - there is no `LongListSelectorItem` in assemly. I thought, it because of that I'm develop WP7.1 app, not WP8. But, when I created new WP8 project and add assemly from example - `LongListSelectorItem` wasn't there. I can't understand where is a problem, assembly has `LongListSelectorItem`, but when I add it to my project - `LongListSelectorItem` disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example uses [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) (formerly Silverlight Phone Toolkit), you should add it to your project.